# Grunt: Running tasks after "jasmine_node"

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, jasmine-node

I'm implementing my own XML/HTML-reporting tool for test-automation using grunt, jasmine_node and some other tools. Unfortunately I need to run some tasks right after jasmine_node --> in fact I only use jasmine_node for creating junit xml reports :D

The problem is: When jasmine is done  with testing, it is exiting the task chain (whether I use forceexit or not). But I need the following tasks to be executed.

See below my config:

```
jasmine_node: {
        options: {
            forceExit: true,
            match: '.',
            matchall: false,
            extensions: 'js',
            specNameMatcher: 'spec',
            includeStackTrace: false,
            jUnit: {
                report: true,
                savePath : "test-automation/test-xml/",
                useDotNotation: true,
                consolidate: true
            }
        },
        all: ['test-automation/test-specs/']
    },
```

And here comes the chain:

```
grunt.registerTask('test', ['jasmine_node', 'junit_xml_merge', 'open', 'connect']);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Setting property `forceExit` to false?

Comment: This won't solve it, because the script will stop anyway, when a testcase is failing --> the consequence of a failing testcase is, that the jasmine_node task is failing and killing the following taskchain. I don't want to have jasmine_node aborting, when it comes to failing tests.